# Pass variables through to control from page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm dynamically loading a user control on to a page. I'm usually a vb.net person and can normally get by but this has me stumped. I'm trying to pass a variable from the page to the control before I load it.

Heres is where I'm calling the control:

```
    Control webUserControl = (Control)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/carousel-guards.ascx");

    phGuardsList.Controls.Add(webUserControl);
```

I've put the following property on the carousel-guards.ascx:

```
public String PostCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.PostCode;
            }
            set
            {
                this.PostCode = value;
            }
        }
```

But I don't seem to have a webUserControl.PostCode available to me.

Any help will be really appreciated

**EDIT -** Of course, I have to reference the control. Silly me! However it's not letting me call it with carousel_guards: `Error   96  The type or namespace name 'carousel_guards' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Development\Guards247\g247 Test\FindGuard.aspx.cs    197 13  g247 Test`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace g247_Test.controls
{
    public partial class carousel_guards : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public String PostCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.PostCode;
            }
            set
            {
                this.PostCode = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from how you wrote the property there is a problem, it is self referencing. To avoid this I usually write internal memebers with a '_' prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the property from your control because you are casting your loaded control to `Control`. You should cast it to your control type. If your Control class name is `CarouselGuards` then you can do:

```
CarouselGuards webUserControl = (CarouselGuards)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/carousel-guards.ascx");
```

and then you can access the property.

```
webUserControl.PostCode = "123";
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I've updated my question with what's wrong if you could take a quick look thanks

Comment: @TomBeech, you need to specify `using g247_Test.controls;` at the top of the code, or right click on `carousel_guards` and select `Resolve`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Class name of your page to work.

```
var webUserControl = (carousel_guards)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/carousel-guards.ascx");

// now works
webUserControl.PostCode = "17673";
phGuardsList.Controls.Add(webUserControl);
```

If you do not have include a reference of the control and not found the name of the class you can insert on aspx the line

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/controls/carousel-guards.ascx" %>
```

Or just drag and drop it inside the page, to make the reference, and then delete the actual control, because you make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Use casting for your control type `CarouselGuards` instead of `Control`

```
CarouselGuards webUserControl = (CarouselGuards)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/carousel-guards.ascx");
webUserControl.PostCode = "XXXX";
```

as a side note don't forget the check null control for the object.